# how to display binded items in gridview for one to many relation table

Tags: c#, list, gridview, checkbox, devexpress

I binded Devexpress gridcontrol, from a list which fetches data from one to many relationed table. I mean, I have one "nID" for many "analiseID"s.

Gridview displays records one under the other like this:

nID  Analises

```
2     A
2     C
2     D
3     A
3     C
```

...

I need gridview to display data; just one record for each nID accourding its analises in the table, and its analises will come with checkbox checked under the analise name. Analise names will be in the caption part of the gridview. Analise fields will display checked near their nID. Like this:

`nID     A         B         C         D         E`  .. (total 34 analises)

```
2    checked             checked     checked
3    checked             checked
```

I'm binding gridcontrol like this:

```
            List<nAnalises> lst = new List<nAnalises>();
            SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                nAnalises na = new nAnalises();
                na.nID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["nID"]);
                na.rNumber = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["rNumner"]);
                na.nName = sdr["nName"].ToString();
                na.analiseID = Convert.ToInt32(sdr["analiseID"]);
                na.analiseName = sdr["analiseName"].ToString();

                lst.Add(na);
            }
            gridControl1.DataSource = lst;
```

Please give me idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must create a Datatable.The number of columns will be the count of your Analises
Then you have to add 1 row for each nID and set the value for each column.

Here is a code sample

```
List<nAnalises> lst = new List<nAnalises>();
lst.Add(new nAnalises() { Id = 2, Name = "A" });
lst.Add(new nAnalises() { Id = 2, Name = "D" });
lst.Add(new nAnalises() { Id = 3, Name = "A" });
lst.Add(new nAnalises() { Id = 3, Name = "C" });


Dictionary<int, string[]> values = 
              (from i in lst
              group i by i.Id into g
              select new { 
                           Id = g.Key,
                           Values = g.Select(ee => ee.Name).Distinct().ToArray() 
                          }
              ).ToDictionary(ee => ee.Id, ee => ee.Values);


DataTable table = new DataTable();
table.Columns.Add("ID");
foreach (var item in values.Values.SelectMany(EE => EE).Distinct())
     table.Columns.Add(item);


foreach (var item in values)
{
    DataRow row = table.NewRow();

     foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
     {
           row[column.ColumnName] = false;
           foreach (var value in item.Value)
              if (value == column.ColumnName)
                  row[value] = column.ColumnName == value;

     }
     row["ID"] = item.Key;
     table.Rows.Add(row);
}
```

and then

```
grid.Datasource=table;
```

if you want to see the table on the console you can use this

```
foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
       Console.Write(string.Format("{0,10}", col.ColumnName) + " ");
Console.WriteLine();
foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
{
   foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
        Console.Write(string.Format("{0,10}", row[col.ColumnName]) + " ");
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

The above example prints

```
    ID          A          D          C 
     2       True       True      False 
     3       True      False       True
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I actually use List<> for datasource. So, I couldn't apply your code. I updated my question. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Updated.I only change the creation of the Dictionary.

Comment: It Works, Thank you! And, what if i need to display more columns? Dictionary has just int and string. I have few more columns like, nName, rName, rNumber coming from the class.

Comment: Add more column below table.Columns.Add("ID");And then below  row["ID"] = item.Key; search and find the details for that ID.(Or you have to change the algorith that creates the table..)